# How do I get Kc from my SIM card?

Tags: gsm, simcard

Since listening to a few Defcon talks on SIM cards and, more recently, the NSA Playset, I've become interested in GSM. [This page](https://srlabs.de/airprobe-how-to/) gives a fairly good tutorial on getting Kraken set up, but apparently for a known-plaintext attack, I need to know the plaintext. The aforementioned tutorial isn't very helpful with this, only saying:

> Note: this step [known-plaintext attack with Kraken] is not as easy as it sounds. Usually capture some calls of your own phone where you know the Kc (it can be read from
>     the SIM or displayed by the Engineering Mode Screen of some phones)
>     and look for known-plain-text candidates. An example are "SYSTEM
>     INFORMATION 5/6/5ter" in the SACCH or "LAPDM U, func=UI" frames.
>     Also keep in mind that there could be wrong bits in a burst due to
>     distortion.

I'm more than happy to do this, as I believe in learning through experimentation (and like playing in traffic), but I'm having trouble finding Kc. I don't have the hardware to read my SIM card while it's connected to my phone (which I think I would need to do, or there wouldn't be any open sessions to have keys for). That leaves this "Engineering Mode Screen." I found several Android apps which say they open Engineering Mode, all of which open a screen entitled "Testing." This gives a great deal of information, but I don't see Kc (or anything that looks like it). Does anyone know how I can find my session key (preferably without buying anything)? Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at : http://domonkos.tomcsanyi.net/?p=369

Comment: @r00t That's exactly what I was looking for! You are clearly stronger in the art of Google-fu than I am. If you'd like to post as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find Kc from a SIM card you have 4 working ways :

(Credits to http://domonkos.tomcsanyi.net/?p=369)

1. BlackBerry Engineering Screen:

> pretty much on all of the BlackBerries you can enable the so called “Engineering Mode” which will simply show you the current Kc.

2. OsmocomBB Mobile App

> Download and install the app
>
> 1. Upload layer1 to your phone
> 2. Run mobile -i 127.0.0.1
> 3. telnet 127.0.0.1 4247
>
> After that simply say: 
>   show subscriber 1 At the top you should see the
>   Kc printed.

3. AT+CSIM Command

You need to send APDU commands to the SIM card via the modem (some phones allow you to do so):

> Sample run:
>
> AT+CSIM=14,"A0A40000026F20"
>   +CSIM: 34,"000000096F2004001100BB010200009000"
>
> OK
>   AT+CSIM=10,"A0B0000009"
>   +CSIM: 22,"E0940FC09AEFA000009000"
>
> OK
>   You find the last Kc used here: E0 94 0F C0 9A EF A0 00 and also the key sequence > number: 00

(From : http://openbsc.osmocom.org/trac/wiki/A5_GSM_AT_tricks)

4. Using a SIM-card reader/Smart Card Reader

You need a PC/SC cardreader and a software like SIMspyII. After insterting the card, you will have Kc displayed.

I just copied the information from http://domonkos.tomcsanyi.net/?p=369 to be sure the information will not disapear if the site goes down.